# setIsStrongBoxBacked() for doesn't throw StrongBoxUnavailableException as expected

Tags: android, keystore

Im recently working with Android keystore system.

A Xiaomi 9 phone and Huawei P20(updated to Android 9) were used for test which might not support StrongBox according to the GrapheneOS/AttestationSamples provided from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671931/list-of-android-smart-phones-that-support-android-strongbox-on-api-28android-pi).

Furthermore, below code returned false indicate that the device doesn't have StrongBox Feature.

```
private boolean hasStrongBox(Context context){
    return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_STRONGBOX_KEYSTORE);
}
```

However, during the test, when I'm generating AES encryption key by using the code below , both of the phone **doesn't** throw StrongBoxUnavailableException:

```
protected int createAndroidKeyStoreSymmetricKey() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");

    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder builder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(ALIAS_MASTER_KEY, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
            .setIsStrongBoxBacked(true);
    
    keyGenerator.init(builder.build());
    secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    if(secretKey != null ){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

While generating RSA encryption key, they both did throw StrongBoxUnavailableException:

```
private KeyPair genKeyPair(String alias, boolean isStrongBoxBacked) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg =
            KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder keyBuilder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            alias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_ECB)
            .setKeySize(CRYPTO_BITS)
            .setIsStrongBoxBacked(true);
    kpg.initialize(keyBuilder.build());

    return kpg.generateKeyPair();
}
```

```
android.security.keystore.StrongBoxUnavailableException: Failed to generate key pair
```

Is there any spec configuration was done wrong during the Key generation? As The expecting result is StrongBoxUnavailableException is thrown even during the AES generation.

Comment: Could you check your createAndroidKeyStoreSymmetricKey() code again? I think it shouldn't compile as there's an additional semicolon in the builder definition after setEncryptionPaddings(...)